# How to use Xpath in HtmlUnit to get access to table inside a bunch of nested divs

Tags: java, html, xpath, htmlunit

I have created a program to get access to a web application using HtmlUnit. After I login to the application, I want to open jobs listed in a table one by one and go to the next page. Unfortunately, the table does not have an id attribute that I can use to getElementById during initialization of HtmlTable variable.

So, I decided to use getByXPath function and pass a path through which the system can identify the table I am referring to and get me going. The problem I am facing here is that the table I want access to is nested under a bunch of divs and a table tag. Hierarchically, the table I am trying to get access lies under the below-mentioned fashion

*HTML -> Body -> 12 divs -> table -> tbody ->tr -> td -> 10 divs -> table*

I could not start from the middle in the Xpath function. So, I passed in the entire path in the following manner:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
     final HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable) page2.getByXPath("//html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[@id='idName']/div/div/div[@class='className']/div/div/div/div/div/table[@class='TableClass']").get(i);
     System.out.println("Printing table: " + table.asText());
}
```

The error I get for this is as follows:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0**

Since the table is buried under a larger number of other tags, I do not know how to get an efficient way to access it.

Now, I tried to use the getChildNodes function to get all nodes present in the page and list the Table nodes alone. The code snippet is here:

```
        List list = page2.getChildNodes();
        int k = 0;
        while(list.iterator() != null)
        {
            HtmlElement anElement = (HtmlElement) list.get(k);
            if(anElement instanceof HtmlTable)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello :" +anElement.asText());
            }
            k =  k + 1;
        }
```

Here I am having a **ClassCastException** for the HtmlElement cast operation.

Comment: I'm sure that there are enough ways to select your table even without `id`. Show `HTML` for this table

Comment: The html for the table is : <table class="className" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="width: 1493px;">

Comment: "I could not start from the middle in the Xpath function.", why? Did you try using a browser tool to test the XPath?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to identify your table using its attributes. Try below `XPath`:

```
//table[@class="className"][@role="presentation"]
```

Comment: I tried it. Did not work. The first table has an id. HTML for that one is 

<table id="tableID" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="width:100%; height:100%" role="presentation">

I used the code 

final HtmlTable table1 = (HtmlTable) page2.getElementById("tableID");

Even this is giving NullPointerException. Not sure why it would not pick the table by id.

Comment: I will try adding that. There are two types of function, getElementById & getHtmlElementById. With the first, I am getting NPE and with the later one, I am getting element not found exception. I am just trying this to see that I can access tables if it has ID. Still not sure on how to deal with my original table of interest

Answer (score 0):

I guess your have a more general problem.
As a first check you can use something like

```
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

to dump your page. Do this to get a idea what your page looks like. Some more sophisticated web pages are doing some client side rendering (this means that parts of the dom will be constructed at the client side from some javascript code). In this case you have to wait for the javascript to finish before you can start trying the controls either by XPath or by gettign the child nodes.

If you are sure the dom tree looks like you expect, you can load the duped page code into firefox and use firebug. Firebug offers a function to generate the XPath expression for a selected dom element.